# sqlite driver in Exe created with pyInstaller crashes with the message NotADirectoryError: MultiplexedPath only supports directories

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

Python 3.10.9
I am using pyInstaller to create an executable. I create it from within a conda environment using;

```
python -m PyInstaller --noconfirm app.spec
```

app.spec has the following contents
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

```
a = Analysis(
    ['E:\\development\\chromDB_server\\app.py'],
    pathex=['C:\\Users\\user\\.conda\\envs\\cuda118', 'C:\\Users\\user\\.conda\\envs\\cuda118\\lib\\site-packages', 'E:\\development\\chromDB_server'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=['onnxruntime', 'tokenizers', 'chromadb.telemetry.posthog', 'chromadb.api.segment','chromadb.db.impl',
'chromadb.db.impl.sqlite','chromadb.migrations', 'chromadb.migrations.embeddings_queue'],
    collectsubmodules=['chromadb', 'chromadb.migrations', 'chromadb.telemetry', 'chromadb.api','chromadb.db'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='app',
    clean=True,
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='app',
)
```

The error when the exe is run is;

```
  ...
  File "chromadb\db\impl\sqlite.py", line 65, in __init__
  File "importlib_resources\_common.py", line 46, in wrapper
  File "importlib_resources\_common.py", line 56, in files
  File "importlib_resources\_common.py", line 113, in from_package
  File "importlib_resources\_compat.py", line 79, in get_resource_reader
  File "importlib_resources\_compat.py", line 56, in _namespace_reader
  File "importlib_resources\readers.py", line 133, in __init__
  File "importlib_resources\readers.py", line 70, in __init__
  NotADirectoryError: MultiplexedPath only supports directories
  [11508] Failed to execute script 'app' due to unhandled exception!
```

Line 65 in sqlite.py is the following

```
self._migration_imports = [
        files("chromadb.migrations.embeddings_queue"),
        ...
    ]
```

I have read about how to test for the frozen environment using code like

```
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # If the application is run as a bundle, the PyInstaller bootloader
    # extends the sys module by a flag frozen=True and sets the app 
    # path into variable _MEIPASS'.
    application_path = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.join('..',os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

but I am not sure how to apply it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar issue with PyInstaller and ChromaDB. As a workaround, I just created an empty file:

```
\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\chromadb\migrations\embeddings_queue\__init__.py
```

This worked in my case. I also did the same for other "Not found" submodules of the chromadb package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and what solved it was adding this line to my spec:

```
datas += collect_data_files('chromadb', include_py_files=True, includes=['**/*.py', '**/*.sql'])
```

Notice that we include .sql files, which is the file that chromadb has on the folder `chromadb.migrations.embeddings_queue`.

This was in addition to have the hidden imports that you already have.